# I am getting an error when using ALIAS in the FROM clause used in SELECT clause.Can any one tell where i am going wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am aware we can use ALIAS in FROM clause at SELECT but its giving error for me.
sample code:-

```
 select a.first_name from( select first_name from EMPLOYEES where first_name='Ellen') as a;
```

my code:-

```
 SELECT a.id_employee FROM(SELECT id_employee FROM table1 union  SELECT id_employee FROM table2) as a;
```

I get the error *00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [oracle: can you assign an alias to the from clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940530/oracle-can-you-assign-an-alias-to-the-from-clause)

Comment: @JonHeller In the case you mentioned ALIAS is working fine for him. But in my case I am getting an error

Comment: Remove the `as` and it will work. Oracle doesn't like that in `FROM` clause.

Comment: @tvm yes it worked well without `AS`  .Thanks.But why is it asked to use `AS` in the case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940530/oracle-can-you-assign-an-alias-to-the-from-clause

Comment: @sql_dummy `AS` can be used for column aliases but not for table aliases.