# Why using AS, while creating ALIAS in FROM causing an error for me?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Can we use `AS` to create an ALIAS in `FROM`.If no,why? .If yes,is it limited to only few cases?(because I am getting an error in my case)

ALIAS in `FROM` without `AS` works perfectly fine

```
  SELECT a.id_employee FROM(SELECT id_employee FROM table1 union  SELECT id_employee FROM table2) a;
```

But why ALIAS in `FROM` using `AS` creates error *00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended"*

```
  SELECT a.id_employee FROM(SELECT id_employee FROM table1 union  SELECT id_employee FROM table2) as a;
```

NOTE: Also I came across the [oracle: can you assign an alias to the from clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940530/oracle-can-you-assign-an-alias-to-the-from-clause) explanations which used `AS` . So can ?

Comment: This is Oracle specific and it is part of its syntax. You probably use MySQL/SQL Server where `AS` is possible for subquery alias, but it is not the case in `Oracle`

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not allow `as` in the `FROM` clause.  Oracle only supports `as` for column aliases.

However, you don't need a subquery for this.  It is simpler to use:

```
SELECT id_employee FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id_employee FROM table2
```